# MySQL: Update column of multiple rows based on another row

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database of Tweets with the following columns

```
+------------------------+--------------+
| Field                  | Type         | 
+------------------------+--------------+
| id                     | varchar(128) |
| message_id             | bigint(20)   |
| message                | text         |
| from_id                | int(12)      |
| cnty                   | int(5)       |
| county                 | varchar(64)  |
| city                   | varchar(64)  |
| state                  | varchar(2)   |
+------------------------+--------------+
```

The database contains multiple messages for each distinct `from_id`. There is one row for each `from_id` that contains `cnty`, `county`, `city`. and `state` and all other rows with the same `from_id` have NULL values for those columns.  I would like to fill them in with the same values for each `from_id`. Is this possible in MySQL? My first thought was to write a Python script to do this, but maybe that is overkill.

Comment: Having so many duplicate values is very inefficient. If you can, you should revisit your db design. Anyway, you can get the data from the first row and use a regular sql query to update all rows with that from_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a subquery that gets all non null values, then use an UPDATE query with a join:

```
UPDATE
  tweets INNER JOIN (
    SELECT from_id, MAX(cnty) AS cnty, MAX(country) AS country, MAX(city) AS city, ...
    FROM tweets
    GROUP BY from_id) m
  ON tweets.from_id = m.from_id
SET
  tweets.cnty=m.cnty,
  tweets.country=m.country,
  tweets.city=m.city,
  ...
```